# how to write [style.display] in line styles in typescript instead

Tags: angular

Hi I have the following 3 examples of some inline styles in my code I need to get rid of in order to meet CSP compliance standards. Can anyone suggest how I can go about setting up a similar logic within the style display tag inside the component typescript file possilby using ngif statements or whatever practice would work best?

```
<div class="ccav-notify-panel-wrapper" *ngIf='ccavShowWarningPanel" [style.display]="!collapseAccountOverview?'inherit':'none'">

<div class="ccav-notify-panel-wrapper" *ngIf='ccavShowErrorPanel" [style.display]="!collapseAccountOverview?'inherit':'none'">

<div id="accountOverviewBody" [style.display]="(!collapseAccountOverview && !ccavShowErrorPanel && !ccavShowWarningPanel)?'inherit':'none'">
```

I figured using something like documnet.getelmentbyid would be a start but looking for some outside suggestions.

Comment: You would just add a property to your component, set the value from the ternary statement you currently have in the template and then use the property as the value of `[style.display]="yourPropertyName"`

Comment: You could do worse than checking out the [inbuilt attribute directives](https://angular.io/guide/built-in-directives#built-in-attribute-directives) which include `ngClass` and `ngStyle`